# How to replace jsx file in Adobe Extension Builder 3

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

After installing eclipse and working on an extension I have a file named photoshop.jsx.

```
$._ext_PHXS={
    run : function() {

        /**********  Replace below sample code with your own JSX code  **********/
        var appName;   
        appName = "Hello Photoshop";   
        alert(appName);
        /************************************************************************/

        return appName;
    },
};
```

And when I replaced the code with my own JSX code it didn't work. What's the problem?

```js
$._ext_PHXS={
 
cTID = function(s) {
    return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
};
sTID = function(s) {
    return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
};
 
 
function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
        return;
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    ref1.putProperty(cTID('Clr '), cTID('FrgC'));
    desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc2.putDouble(cTID('Rd  '), 187.996108949416);
    desc2.putDouble(cTID('Grn '), 125.003891050584);
    desc2.putDouble(cTID('Bl  '), 94);
    desc1.putObject(cTID('T   '), sTID("RGBColor"), desc2);
    desc1.putString(cTID('Srce'), "eyeDropperSample");
    executeAction(cTID('setd'), desc1, dialogMode);
};
step1();      // Set
```

Comment: I think the brace after `_ext_PHXS` should be an object instead of a function body. `{ cTID = ...; }` there doesn't make sense; it should be `{ run: someValue; }` where `someValue` is expected to be a function. Did you read the error message?